# Should I include 'www' in the common name of a SSL cert request?

Tags: ssl

I'm about to purchase a SSL certificiate for a small website. Is it best practice to enter 'www.domainName.com' or 'domainName.com' for the common name?

Comment: Probably a better question for http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you use the `subjectAltName` field, and include all variations of the hostname(s) you want to use, or a wildcard if you aren't sure what all the variations will be. The common name (CN) is only used as a backup. See [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) for more details:

> ###3.1.  Server Identity
>
> In general, HTTP/TLS requests are generated by dereferencing a URI.
> As a consequence, the hostname for the server is known to the client.
> If the hostname is available, the client MUST check it against the
> server's identity as presented in the server's Certificate message,
> in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.
>
> If the client has external information as to the expected identity of
> the server, the hostname check MAY be omitted. (For instance, a
> client may be connecting to a machine whose address and hostname are
> dynamic but the client knows the certificate that the server will
> present.) In such cases, it is important to narrow the scope of
> acceptable certificates as much as possible in order to prevent man
> in the middle attacks.  In special cases, it may be appropriate for
> the client to simply ignore the server's identity, but it must be
> understood that this leaves the connection open to active attack.
>
> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.
>
> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character * which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but
> not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.
>
> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.
>
> If the hostname does not match the identity in the certificate, user
> oriented clients MUST either notify the user (clients MAY give the
> user the opportunity to continue with the connection in any case) or
> terminate the connection with a bad certificate error. Automated
> clients MUST log the error to an appropriate audit log (if available)
> and SHOULD terminate the connection (with a bad certificate error).
> Automated clients MAY provide a configuration setting that disables
> this check, but MUST provide a setting which enables it.
>
> Note that in many cases the URI itself comes from an untrusted
> source. The above-described check provides no protection against
> attacks where this source is compromised. For example, if the URI was
> obtained by clicking on an HTML page which was itself obtained
> without using HTTP/TLS, a man in the middle could have replaced the
> URI.  In order to prevent this form of attack, users should carefully
> examine the certificate presented by the server to determine if it
> meets their expectations.