# install www and non-www ssl cert apache

Tags: apache, ssl

My site (prestashop based) has a certificate for the domain name without the www. After receiving complaints from a client, we wanted to add a certificate for the www.

We are running Apache. What is the best way to install the second cert we just bought? Is it possible to install 2 certificates on Apache for the different host variations, or should I buy a third wild card cert?

Is it possible to easily manipulate prestashop to use the canonical name, i.e. redirect all links to the www version?

Comment: You could use 2 certs (via SNI), but it's often better to use a single cert valid for both (since not every client supports SNI). A wildcard in itself will not help you with the non-www domain (although most wildcard would have the non-www SAN too).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Webmasters.SE might be a better place.

Comment: If you have a cert for `example.com`, you usually use one certificate with multiple Subject Alt Names (SANs). The one certificate would have a SAN for `example.com`, a SAN for `www.example.com`, etc.

Comment: Webmasters.SE doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to buy cert for www.example.com. It works both for and without www.

During the CSR creation put your domain with `www` (common name (CN) field in the CSR).

According to the [geocerts.com](https://www.geocerts.com/faq#csr9):

**What is the Common Name (CN) in the CSR?**

> The Common Name (CN) is the
>   fully-qualified domain name for your web server. This must be an exact
>   match. For example: if you intend to secure the URL
>   https://www.yourdomain.com, then your CSR's Common Name must be
>   www.yourdomain.com.

**Should I have a 'www' in my CSR's Common Name?**

> If you want to secure
>   both the www and non-www version of your site it is recommended that
>   you use 'www.mydomain.comn' in your CSR.

This question may be also helpful:

[Should I include 'www' in the common name of a SSL cert request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711511/should-i-include-www-in-the-common-name-of-a-ssl-cert-request)